# cannot use $slice in nested array

Tags: mongodb

what i try is to `$slice` an array inside an array.

This is what i tried but it fails.

```
db.collection.find({
  name: "admin",
  "datasets.name": "test"
},
{
  "datasets.$.datapoints": {
    $slice: [
      0,
      3
    ]
  }
})
```

Example input data

```
[
  {
    "name": "admin",
    "datasets": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          6,
          4,
          3,
          8,
          5,
          3
        ],
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "619288f16733758444a28728"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "more datasets",
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
          6,
          7,
          8
        ],
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "619289086733758444a2872a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Playground link:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/pmGpk9jtqZ2

Output should be:

```
{ name: "test", datapoints: [1,6,4] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results you want

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "datasets": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("619288f16733758444a28728"),
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          6,
          4
        ],
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("619289086733758444a2872a"),
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ],
        "name": "more datasets"
      }
    ],
    "name": "admin"
  }
]
```

with

```js
db.collection.find({
  name: "admin",
  "datasets.name": "test"
},
{
  "datasets.datapoints": {
    $slice: [
      0,
      3
    ]
  }
})
```

You just had to omit the positional operator.

Comment: It's not what I want. You have 2 datasets but I need just the 1 searched

Comment: When you run this on a real MDB instance, it should execute the find correctly, only processing the right doc.